# Meaning of も vs でも for "even"

Tags: grammar, meaning, particles, particle-も, particle-でも

I'm wondering about the difference between も and でも for their "even" meaning.

Using example sentences from A Dictionary of Basic Japanese Grammar,

> 私は難しい仕事**でも**する。(original, pg 112)
>
> 私は難しい仕事**も**する。(swapped for も)

and

> 私はこんな難しい漢字**も**読める。(original, pg 250)
>
> 私はこんな難しい漢字**でも**読める。(swapped for でも)

Are the swapped sentences grammatically correct? If so, is there a difference in nuance?

Comment: I can't give a good answer, but depending on context も might translate more naturally as 'also' in your examples, but でも would always mean 'even'.

Comment: That could indeed be a valid translation. However, the grammar dictionary I took these sentences from distinguishes between the "also" も and the "even" も. The "even" も is specifically used in the sentence `私はこんな難しい漢字も読める`, with the translation `I can read even difficult kanji like this` (pg 250). So assuming these are accurate, my question is whether でも can be substituted in without a change in meaning.

Comment: I would think it's possible to not change the meaning but it does however change the nuance. Not 100% certain, but it's my (maybe mistaken) understanding that using も implies a standard "as well" whereas でも implies an "as well" with the tone of "against the odds". So, 私は難しい仕事でもする -> "I will even do difficult jobs", whereas 私は難しい仕事もする -> "I will also do difficult jobs"

Answer (score 8):

There is a difference in nuance. でも implies  that **"normally it isn't but in this case it is"**.

> 私は難しい仕事**でも**する。

This implies that 通常私は簡単な仕事しかしないが・・・実は難しい仕事でもするよ。(I normally do only easy jobs, but actually I can also do difficult ones.)

> 私は難しい仕事**も**する。

This implies that the person speaking normally does easy, (moderate), and difficult jobs. No emphasis is given that s/he "can also" do difficult jobs. S/he has always done them too.

Let's use another example:

> この映画は小さな子ども**でも**楽しめる。

Movies like this are **normally perceived to be only enjoyable for a certain age group**, e.g. teens and above. However, **this particular one is actually enjoyable also for little kids**, like toddlers, pre-schoolers, grade school kids, etc.

> この映画は小さな子ども**も**楽しめる。

This movie is enjoyable also for little kids, and nothing is special about it. It has always been like that.

Comment: What would be "I eat tonight, I even drink!" 飲んでも？飲むことでも？That's easy when it's a noun but not when it's an action.

Answer (score 4):

I am not quite sure whether this is a general answer but as for the two examples, they are both gramattically correct while there is a slight difference in nuance.
でも is more a "even if", while も is "even/also"

examples:

> > 私は難しい仕事でもする。

"I will do any job EVEN IF it was difficult."

> > 私は難しい仕事もする。

"(I will do easy jobs) AND ALSO difficult jobs."

Note that でも is a short form of であっても or であったとしても at least for these two sentences.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are grammatically correct, and yes the nuance is different.

「も」implies that there is a list, and that the stated item is just one item in that list.「でも」could refer to the item in isolation.  So in the example sentences:

---

> 私は難しい仕事でもする

Even if the work is difficult I'll do it.

*(This sentence implies that there is difficult work, but that there may not be any easy work.)*

> 私は難しい仕事もする。

I'll do difficult work as well.

*(This sentence implies that there is both difficult work and easy work.)*

---

> 私はこんな難しい漢字も読める。

I can also read difficult kanji.

*(This sentence implies that there are both difficult kanji and easy kanji. For example: a newspaper article.)*

> 私はこんな難しい漢字でも読める。

Even if the kanji is difficult I can even read it.

*(This sentence implies that there are difficult kanji, but that there may not be any easy kanji. For example: classical Japanese texts.)*

---

These interpretations are supported by the following unofficial sources:

- [助詞関連 Q147](http://nhg.pro.tok2.com/qa/joshi-15.htm)
- [「も」と「でも」の違い](https://oshiete.goo.ne.jp/qa/6610118.html)